# DatagramSocket - binding localhost socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp

The [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#DatagramSocket(int)) lists this constructor:

`DatagramSocket (int port)`

Does this mean that once port is bound to a `DatagramSocket`, any UDP traffic will go through that port, irrespective of whether the `DatagramSocket` is used to send/receive the data?

Answer (score 1):

Once a remote port is bound to given socket all the traffic between local port and remote one (bound using `connect`) will go using that `DataGramSocket`.

Comment: Here is what I tried:
1. Create a `DatagramSocket` (empty constructor)
2. Use `Network.bindSocket(DatagramSocket)`
3. Then, `DatagramSocket.connect(InetAddress, port)`
4. Get bound local port by calling `getLocalPort()`
4. Now, if I specify this local port obtained from step #4 in a streaming player, I get an exception which says the socket is already in use.